# .Net parallel WaitAll()

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I have a situation in my code where i'm starting unknown number of tasks and would like to use `Task.WaitAll()`.

something like this:

```
if (condition) 
{ 
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (call the web service1...);
} 

if (condition) 
{ 
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew (call the web service2...);
}

if (condition) 
{ 
    var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew (call the web service3...); 
}

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

The problem is that i can't say

```
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2 , task3)
```

because i don't know which one of them will actually start.
Any idea for a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the list of Tasks and add your tasks into list dynamically:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

if (condition) 
{ 
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew (call the web service1...);
    tasks.Add(task);
} 

if (condition) 
{ 
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew (call the web service2...);
     tasks.Add(task2);
}

if (condition) { 
    var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew (call the web service3...); 
    tasks.Add(task3);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a list of actually started tasks and do `Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray())`

```
if(condition)
{
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (call the web service1...);
    taskList.Add(task1);
}
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is possible to save the list of tasks to the List (tasks) and use the 
following code:

```
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

See [How to: Wait on One or More Tasks to Complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx). You can wait on an array of `Task`s.